# How to report "Ocean of Knowledge"

Tags: research, academia

I would write an academic research report and i would like to know how to write :

> "Ocean of knowledge"

to describe an enormous source of knowledge ?

Answer (score 6):

I think in my neck of the woods it'd be more idiomatic to speak of a *(vast) sea of knowledge*. But a *(great) ocean of knowledge* is okay, indeed if you google around you will see many many people using it.

Comment: There's also the [Ocean Sea](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93527/what-is-the-ocean-sea)

Answer (score 3):

[Universe of Knowledge](http://www.iva.dk/bh/Lifeboat_KO/CONCEPTS/universe_of_knowledge.htm) is another metaphor:

> - "Universe of knowledge" is a metaphor that has been important in library classification theory.

Source: http://www.iva.dk/bh/Lifeboat_KO/CONCEPTS/universe_of_knowledge.htm

Answer (score 3):

A *body of knowledge* is a collection of all concepts and ideas within a particular field. The word "body" doesn't imply massiveness on its own, but the full term is typically understood to refer to a mass of information sufficiently large to describe an entire domain of knowledge, which must inherently be quite large.